# How to shift all clicks on screen to a small distance?

Tags: android

I have a annoying issue with my android phone (Android 4.4, API Level 19).
When I touch the screen, the contact point is shifted some millimeters at left, it's a big problem to write a sms or some text. 
Is there a setting to correct the problem, or is it possible to build an invisible `Service` in foreground that take the touch and send it back at the right position ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem device specific ? Then you should format your internal memory or flash a new official rom aviailable